# При создании MessageBox'a WinApi открывается еще и консоль

Tags: c++, winapi, visual-studio-code

```
#include <windows.h>

int CALLBACK WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance,HINSTANCE hPrevInstance,LPSTR cmdLine,int cmdShow){
    while(MessageBox(nullptr,"Press yes","Test",MB_YESNO)!=6){};
    return 0;
}
```

При запуске открывается окно консоли,Visual Studio Code

Comment: ¿Это только при запуске из Visual Studio Code такое происходит?

Comment: У меня на пк всё запускается без консоли,но когда я скидываю готовый exe'шник другу у него она появляется,на Visual Studi'и такого не было

Comment: А вы его не консольным случайно сделали?

Answer (score 0):

В MinGW консоль отключается флагом линковщика `-mwindows`.

Причем, независимо от флага можно использовать классический `main()`, и, похоже, `WinMain` тоже.